# How to get rid of hidden HTML text within picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, text

I'm creating a test 'buy now' button located here - http://www.moonechoaudio.com/terms-conditions/ Make sure to scroll to the bottom and see the buy button. As you can see there is the text 'fire refill' below it. How can I get rid of this text? Here is the code for the button. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery Selz Plugin</title>
        <link href="http://cdn.selz.com/jquery/1.0.3/jquery.selz.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>

            <li{list-style-type: none;}><a href="http://selz.co/1triLby">Buy now</a></li>
        </ul>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.selz.com/jquery/1.0.3/jquery.selz.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
        $.selz({
        buttonBg: "#60aae0",
        buttonText: "#fff",
        prefetch: true,
        onDataReady: function ($link, data) {
        $link.html('<img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/53752a6de4b0aefc671bc01d    /53e3fae6e4b0941835a9aac8/53e3fae6e4b0d4852873ddd5/1407449840921 /Screen%20Shot%202014-08-07%20at%205.35.42%20PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '"><br>' + data.Title);
        },
        onModalOpen: function ($link) {
        console.log("Overlay opened!");
        },
        onPurchase: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        onProcessing: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
        });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That text is coming from the `data.Title` that your code is adding after the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove it from the code. Locate the code :

```
buttonText: "#fff",
prefetch: true,
onDataReady: function ($link, data) {
$link.html('<img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/53752a6de4b0aefc671bc01d    /53e3fae6e4b0941835a9aac8/53e3fae6e4b0d4852873ddd5/1407449840921 /Screen%20Shot%202014-08-07%20at%205.35.42%20PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '"><br>' + data.Title);
},
```

and change the `<br>' + data.Title` to just a `'` so it looks like this:

```
buttonText: "#fff",
prefetch: true,
onDataReady: function ($link, data) {
$link.html('<img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/53752a6de4b0aefc671bc01d    /53e3fae6e4b0941835a9aac8/53e3fae6e4b0d4852873ddd5/1407449840921 /Screen%20Shot%202014-08-07%20at%205.35.42%20PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '">');
},
```

Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

remove the last data.Title

```
$link.html('<img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/53752a6de4b0aefc671bc01d    /53e3fae6e4b0941835a9aac8/53e3fae6e4b0d4852873ddd5/1407449840921 /Screen%20Shot%202014-08-07%20at%205.35.42%20PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '">');
```

or, if your really need your text to be there, you can use CSS to use a background image instead and then indent your text. just add a class/id to your anchor tag and then:

```
#your-link {
    background-image:url('imageURL.jpg');
    text-indent:-9999em;
}
```

or... you can just give the link a transparent color. but that's just weird.

```
#your-link {
    color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`$link.html('<img src="http://static....0PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '"><br>' + data.Title);`

to

`$link.html('<img src="http://static....0PM.png?format=1500w"' + data.ImageUrlSmall + '" alt="' +   data.Title + '"><br>' );`